# Como criar uma mensagem no Zenity para todos os usuários logados no Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, display

Uso um script que é executado pelo cron de 1 em 1 hora que tem a finalidade de buscar atualizações e atualizar o sistema.

Queria que o usuário fosse avisado que iniciou a atualização para que o mesmo não desligasse o computador, e quando terminasse a atualização outra mensagem avisando.

Consegui fazer isso com o Zenity, exportando o `DISPLAY=0`, o problema é que cada seção inciada é um novo `DISPLAY`, e se tiver mais de um usuário logado e ele não for o `DISPLAY 0` não vai receber a mensagem.

Existe algum parâmetro parecido com `export DISPLAY=all`, para que a mensagem fosse enviada para todos usuários independente de quem esteja no `DISPLAY 0`?

Meu sistema é o Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Script que estou usando para teste:

```bsh
#!bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0 && zenity --warning --width=600 --title="Atualização automática do sistema" --text "Caro usuário, o sistema encontra-se em processo de atualização no momento, por favor, não desligue o computador até que a atualização seja concluída. Não se preocupe, o sistema irá avisa-lô assim que for finalizado!

Versão atual do sistema: 2.5
Versão da atualização: TESTE
" 
sleep 5s
export DISPLAY=:0 && zenity --warning --width=600 --title="Atualização automática do sistema" --text "A atualização do sistema foi concluída com sucesso, por favor reinicie o computador para aplicar as alterações. 

Aproveite para tomar um café!

Versão anterior do sistema: 2.5
Versão atual do sistema: 2.6
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando "w -h" mostra o usuário que está logado e ativo e logo a frente o DISPLAY que está sendo utilizado, sabendo disso usei o "awk" para extrair esta informação, ficando desta forma no script:

```
export DISPLAY=$(w -h | awk '$2 ~ /:[0-9.]*/{print $2}')
```